# Realm database linkingObjects

Tags: javascript, database, react-native, nosql, realm

While going through the docs encountered these lines on linkingObjects properties please explain them:

> "When accessing linkingObjects properties, a Results object is
>   returned, so further querying and sorting are fully supported.
>   linkingObject properties belong to the object they were acquired from
>   and can not be set or manipulated directly. They are updated
>   automatically when a transaction is committed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@LinkingObjects` is an inverse relationship `0...*` that can be automatically evaluated when an object has a `0...1` or `0...*` relation to another table.

So when `A` has a property `cats` to `RealmList<Cat>`, then `Cat` table can have linking objects property to `A` via `linkingObjects("cats")`, which is a `RealmResults<A>`.

What it says however is that you cannot *remove* items directly from linking objects because it is a computed property, items are only removed from linking objects if the item is removed from the not-inverse relation (the list), or the item is deleted.

When an item is deleted in a transaction, removal of item from linking objects is immediate.